# ggplot density plot change legend background and square fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

In a ggplot density plot, how do I change legend background and fill color of the squares in the legend?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0"),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#F0F0F0"))
```

Doing both at once can give the illusion that the square fill is transparent.

[image]